# how to work with a List of uploaded files in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, upload

I'm sorry, I didn't find such a question, so I created a new one.

I studying Java, and this is my first real practice project.
I need to make a file Parser. So i did it for one file and it works.
But i need it to work with file directory.

So, in View i've changed

```
File to parse: <input type="file" th:field="*{address}" id="address">
```

on

```
File to parse: <input type="file" th:field="*{address}" id="address" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

It works pretty good in View, I can choose all the directory now.

But how should i change my Controller to work not with one file but a List of files?
Should i create new Model?

Another way i see, to select in View the WAY to directory, not files. But i didnt find, how to do it, with using File Explorer (like browser does with input type="file").

Also, i did the class, which can parse few files. The main proplem how to make a "relationship" with view and logic in case of many files.

Can somebody help?
Thanks a lot!

My File model:

```
public class File {
    private String address;

    public File() {
    }

    public File(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/parser")
public class ParserController {


    private final FileParser fileParser;

    @Autowired
    public ParserController(FileParser fileParser) {
        this.fileParser = fileParser;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String parser(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("file", new File());
        return "parser/parser";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("file") File file) throws IOException {
        FileParser.parse(file);
        return "parser/done";
    }
}
```

My Parser (its not a real logic, just as example):

```
@Component
public class FileParser {
    public static void parse(File file) throws IOException {
        Path pathFrom = Path.of(file.getAddress());
        Path pathTo = Files.createFile(Path.of("C:\\Users\\Xiaomi\\Desktop\\parsedtest.txt"));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list = Files.readAllLines(pathTo);
        list.add("file");
        list.add("was");
        list.add("parsed");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(pathTo));
        PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(fos);
        printer.flush();
        printer.close();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(String.valueOf(pathTo));
        for (String lister:
                list) {
            writer.write(lister+"\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    }
```

And View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MEL Parser</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/parser" th:object="${file}">
    File to parse: <input type="file" th:field="*{address}" id="address" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Parse">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to receive multiple files in one method try this

```
@RequestMapping("/saveProducts")
public String uploadResources( HttpServletRequest servletRequest, 
                             @ModelAttribute Product product,
                             Model model) 
{
    //Get the uploaded files and store them
    List<MultipartFile> files = product.getImages();
}
```

Also, a solution, in this case, can be javascript code placed on your page that will send files one by one

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping
    public String create(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                         @ModelAttribute("filesList") FilesList filesList,
                         Model model) throws IOException {
        List<MultipartFile> files = filesList.getAddresses();
        List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        if (null != files && files.size() > 0){
            for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {
                String address = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
                addresses.add(address);
            }
        }
            FileParser.parse(addresses);
        return "parser/done";
    }
```